# ZSH osascript tell parent application (process) display dialog

Tags: applescript, zsh, osascript

I have an AppleScript application that runs a do shell script of my script.sh in the application package.

That my script.sh does some interaction with the user through
$osascript -e 'tell me to button returned of (display dialog "blabla.Do you want blabla." buttons {"yes", "no"})')

The dialogs seem to have no "owner", kind of system wide. Whatever application is forefront, clicking on the dialogs windows doesn't change the forefront application to any other.

Is it possible to get the parent application name and pass it so the dialogs would "owned"by the original AppleScript app?

Comment: The parent would be `osascript` - are you talking about the dialog’s icon?

Comment: I did not care really about icon. 
So osascript  is the parent of the dialog, zsh is the parent of oasascript, and the AppleScript application that launches the zsh script the parent of the zsh. Is it possible to, in the osascript, tell the parent or grandparent? How? The usual applescript/osascript is tell application “my app”. How do I replace myapp with a reference to parent etc.

Comment: `osascript` is what is creating the scripting component instance.  Calling other applications or shell scripts don’t create inheritance chains like that.  What _exactly_ are you trying to do?